# ASP.Net MVC DropdownList and selected value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was able to create a dropdownlist for my MVC project, but the value is not selected as  selected value on the dropdownlist. It just shows whole county list from the first.The value is from database. I tried find it from previous post, but it was quite confusing. Please, suggest me for any idea.

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult Edit(int i)
{
     var items = new SelectList(db.MST_COUNTRies.ToList(), "COUNTRY_ID", "COUNTRY_NM");
     ViewData["MST_COUNTRies"] = items;
}
```

View Code

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("COUNTRY_ID", (SelectList)ViewData["MST_COUNTRies"])%>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624828/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-selectedvalue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you using a strongly typed views (no need of `ViewData` and magic strings). As always start by defining your view model class:

```
public class CountriesViewModel
{
    public int? SelectedCountryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

Then your controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        // TODO: Fetch those from your DB
        var countries = new[] 
        {
            new { Id = 1, Name = "Country 1" },
            new { Id = 2, Name = "Country 2" },
        };

        var model = new CountriesViewModel
        {
            Countries = new SelectList(countries, "Id", "Name", id)
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And finally your strongly typed view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SomeNs.Models.CountriesViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.SelectedCountryId, 
            Model.Countries, 
            "-- Select Country --") 
    %>

</asp:Content>
```

Now when you call `/home/index` you get no country selected, but when you pass the `id` to this action like `/home/index/2` you get the country with this id selected.

Remark: If you are using ASP.NET MVC 1.0 you won't have the strongly typed DropDownListFor helper and you could use this instead:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
        "SelectedCountryId", 
        Model.Countries, 
        "-- Select Country --") 
%>
```

Comment: "TODO: Fetch those from your DB"

Do I fetch data from like this? 

new SelectList(db.MST_COUNTRies.ToList(), "COUNTRY_ID", "COUNTRY_NM");"

Comment: Yeap, this could work. Of course you shouldn't forget the last parameter which sets the selected value: `new SelectList(db.MST_COUNTRies.ToList(), "COUNTRY_ID", "COUNTRY_NM", id);`. Also you should avoid accessing the database directly from your controller but abstracting it into a repository so that you could easily unit test your controllers in isolation. But that's not related to your question, it's just good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int i)
{
     var items = new SelectList(db.MST_COUNTRies.ToList(), "COUNTRY_ID", "COUNTRY_NM", yourSelectedCountryId);
     ViewData["COUNTRY_ID"] = items;
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("COUNTRY_ID"); %>
```

Some notes:

- The "yourSelectedCountryId" argument in new SelectList() can be used to determine the item that should be initially selected.  Assuming that COUNTRY_ID is an int, this argument should also be an int.
- If you populate ViewData with an IEnumerable that matches the name/id of the DropDownList, the Html.DropDownList() call automatically finds it and uses it.  That's why I changed ViewData["MST_COUNTRies"] to ViewData["COUNTRY_ID"].  It saves a little code, and I found myself forced to use this approach to work around a bug in MVC v1.

Comment: I changed them, but still same thing happened. The value from database is not selected on the dropdownlist. I am using a ViewModel like " return View(new EducationViewModel(empEducation));".
Do you think it might be a reason?

Comment: Yes, the ViewModel might impact it.  Does EducationViewModel also have a field called COUNTRY_ID?  If so, its COUNTRY_ID value might override the default value from the new SelectList() call, and you'd need to set it to your database value for my approach to work.  Also, make sure the database value is an actual country ID, not a country name, object of type MST_COUNTRY, etc.  It has to be an ID that would match the COUNTRY_ID property of the countries you're passing to the SelectList.